# Youtube is not counting views for embedded link on our site

Tags: youtube

Issue: The YouTube video embedded in our web application uses the sample code below. When the user plays the video, the view count on the YouTube channel doesn't get updated. Though our website shows up in the list of viewers for the channel, the view count contributions from our website is 0. Findings so far When tested from localhost and DEV(internal purpose) the youtube view count is updated .When used from our domain site, the YouTube viewers count doesn’t update.

Code:

```
<template>
    <youtube id="youtube" :video-id="embedId" ref="youtube" :player-vars="playerVars" disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload" fitParent muted @ready="onReady" @playing="playing" @paused="paused"/>
</template>
 
<script>
export default {
        data() {
        return {
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            controls: 0,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            rel: 0,
            start: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            showsearch: 0,
            playsinline: 1,
},
  
computed: {
    player() {
            return this.$refs.youtube.player
        }
}
methods: {
        playVideo() {
            this.player.playVideo()
        },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide much more detail with your question in order for anyone to realistically be able to help you. Please share your code and include enough information so that others might be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you for providing more detail with your question.  It's best to add that information to the original question rather than as comments.  It's common that readers won't take the time to read comments.  When you add this information to the original question, please mark any code with the proper formatting.

Comment: Typically, views which do not use the original embed code provided by youtube do not count. It also looks like you're using your own player, which could be an additional issue.